# Combine text shadow with a text outline?

Tags: html, css, fonts, border, shadow

I need to recreate this title with the border and shadow. The source is Sigmar. Any ideas?

[image]

[Rasca y Gana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXJBV.png)

I need to recreate this title with the border and shadow. The source is Sigmar.

Comment: You need to provide some working code and what you've attempted thus far yourself.

Comment: Michaela: Did my answer meet your requirements? If so could you mark it as accepted please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) and [drop-shadow](https://css-irl.info/drop-shadow-the-underrated-css-filter/). I've also used [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) to tighten the gap between letters and reduced the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) to crunch the 1st and 2nd lines together. See marked up code below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.text {
  font-family: "Sigmar One", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  line-height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffc502;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 4rem;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #720E0E;
  text-stroke: 2px #720e0e;
  filter: drop-shadow(-0.35rem 0.35rem 0rem #a60000);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
<div class='text'>Rasca<br> y Gana</div>
```